# Binary XML file line #: Error inflating class <unknown> using an ArrayAdapter and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

So I get this error message:

```
...
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
```

on MainActivity.java

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    ...
    loadBalanceTable(inThePast, inTheFuture);
    ...
}

private void loadBalanceTable(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
    AsyncBalanceLoader asyncBalanceLoader = new AsyncBalanceLoader(getApplicationContext(), this);
    asyncBalanceLoader.execute(startDate, endDate);
}
```

AsyncBalanceLoader.java

```
public class AsyncBalanceLoader extends AsyncTask<Calendar, Integer, ArrayList<Balance>> {

    private Context context;
    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private ListView balanceView;

    public AsyncBalanceLoader(Context ctx, AppCompatActivity act) {
        context = ctx;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Balance> doInBackground(Calendar... date) {
        ...
        ArrayList<Balance> arrayListBalance = new ArrayList<Balance>();
        ...
        return arrayListBalance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Balance> arrayListBalance) {
        BalanceArrayAdapter balanceArrayAdapter = new BalanceArrayAdapter(context, arrayListBalance);
        balanceView.setAdapter(balanceArrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

BalanceArrayAdapter.java

```
public class BalanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public BalanceArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Balance> balance) {
        super(context, 0, balance);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.single_balance_line, parent, false);
        }
        ...
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

The problem appears when BalanceArrayAdapter.java on line

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.single_balance_line, parent, false);
```

I was not having any problems back when all this was done on the User Interface thread.

Any ideas on what's happening?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was causing the error by dissecting the error code

```
...
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
...
```

Weirdly, this xml layout file was properly getting inflated when the whole process was ran under the UI thread (on a previous version of the program); however, when it was getting inflated on the `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask` extended class `AsyncBalanceLoader`, although UI thread also, I was getting the error. Here's the problematic xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The second `LinearLayout` is doing nothing and the first one (a.k.a. root view) is only containing one child, defying the purpose of a `LinearLayout` group view.

So, I don't really know where's the "error" per say, but this was the cause.

I changed it for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully somebody will explain later the in-depths of the real cause.